# Dialogflow inline editor function exception: Webhook call failed. Error: UNKNOWN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

In dialogflow i have tried to add my fulfillment code directly in the inline editor for one my Intent response, but its failing. In Diagnostic info its showing the message:

```
Webhook call failed. Error: UNKNOWN. WebhookStatus code: 2
```

I tried to execute the function from Cloud function console directly and its working.

Inline editor code:
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FxTu.png

Error description image added below
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOWor.png

Comment: Can you post the entire diagnostic info as text in your question, along with your entire inline code? My first guess would be that your intent isn't called `RichMessageIntent`, which is causing your fulfillment to run, no handler in your intent map to get hit, and no response being sent - so your fulfillment is crashing out.

Comment: Hi Pramod, James's comment make sense, I have found [this post](https://github.com/actions-on-google/codelabs-nodejs/issues/63) with similar error and more insights where it is also recommended: *1) delete the agent and create a new one from scratch* and *2) clear browser cache*.

Answer (score 0):

Besides re-creating the Agent from scratch and clear browser cache:

- Ensure your [intent name matches the name of the intent handler](https://github.com/actions-on-google/codelabs-nodejs/issues/63) defined in the fulfilment code.
- In this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/161406006) (PIT) the permissions can be another cause of the issue, so, check that [`allUsers`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#controlling_access_on_all_functions_in_a_project) is correctly set in your GCP project for the Fulfillment cloud function.

If the issue persists, according to the PIT, a workaround is to disable the Webhook and re-deploy. Once the deploy is done, disable the Inline Editor and utilize the Webhook URL again.

You can click the Vote for the PIT and get email notifications icon (the star) to register your support for the feature or add your specific issue.